# Getting drawing cache is not including the views which are recently made visible programatically

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have a root `RelativeLayout` and trying to capture the whole view, before capturing the view i am changing the visibility of some views.

My problem is the items which are made visible recently is not in the bitmap of drawing cache.

The top screen is looks good in bitmap but at the place of bottom screen there is a black color instead of the view (`llTagline`) which is made visible programatically. `llTagline` is really visible on screen after this code executes but not in the bitmap.

I have seen lot of quesitons about drawing cache on **SO** but there is no solution for my problem.

Here is my code.

`rlEditorParent` is the root layout of my activity which is `RelativeLayout`.

```
   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            llBottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llTagline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            llTopBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ivRemoveFinish.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            rlEditorParent.invalidate();
            rlEditorParent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            rlEditorParent.destroyDrawingCache();
            rlEditorParent.buildDrawingCache(true);
            finalBitmap = rlEditorParent.getDrawingCache(true);
        }};
```

I have also tried

```
finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rlEditorParent.getWidth(),
                    rlEditorParent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(finalBitmap);
            rlEditorParent.layout(rlEditorParent.getLeft(),
                    rlEditorParent.getTop(), rlEditorParent.getRight(),
                    rlEditorParent.getBottom());
            rlEditorParent.draw(c);
```

**My real screen in app is**

[image: My real screen in the app is]

**What i am getting in finalBitmap is**

[image: What i am getting in finalBitmap]

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        llBottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llTagline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        llTopBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ivRemoveFinish.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rlEditorParent.invalidate();
        rlEditorParent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);            
        rlEditorParent.buildDrawingCache(true);
        finalBitmap = rlEditorParent.getDrawingCache(true);
        rlEditorParent.destroyDrawingCache();
    }};
```

Try this.

Comment: after executing the last line the bitmap will recycle. then how can i furture process with that bitmap like saving it to sd card? Its throwing exception.

Comment: Then try rlEditorParent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); after bitmap is generated instead of rlEditorParent.destroyDrawingCache(); in my answer

Comment: again exception and crashed.

Comment: Can you post exception here?

Comment: but the saved bitmap is looking like the second image i posted. after saving the bitmap its doesn't matter what we are doing in our code

Comment: llBottombar is the linearlayout. i am setting it to gone and make another layout visible. after doing this in the app it looks perfect but in bitmap there is black tile

Comment: Ok.I have faced similar issue with Framelayout and got it resolved by rlEditorParent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); after bitmap is generated hence I gave you above solutions but here it is not working for you.So will have to look at another solution.